# Javascript date daylight savings issue

Tags: javascript, dst

I am facing an issue with daylight savings in javascript while working with dates. The country concerned is UK.

Earlier, before 31st March, the following code gave accurate date:

```
var caseClosed = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), 
now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
```

So, when I used this for differentiating between two dates, the date retrieved by above code and another date (which is from a legacy system which is storing correct date as per system date time), I got a positive correct value.

But after that date, say today, whenever I use the above code, I am getting an hour less; which is resulting in negative value between the two dates.

Say, for example if the time is 18:06, I am getting it as 17:06 by using the above code. So I tried using the following code and it gives me correct time now:

```
var caseClosed = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 
now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
```

Can anyone please explain what is happening and if the above code (without using UTC thing) will work even when DayLight savings is off by not giving an extra hour (60 mins)?

Comment: The above code is *correctly* showing that it's (at the time of this writing) 17:26 in UTC. You need to decide whether you want to use UTC or not...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the UTC date is different from the system date. While the system date is impacted by daylight changes, the UTC is not.... Note that if you wish to use this value to store anything on the server, you should use server time, not client time...

Comment: Well, actually I will explain the scenario. It happens that we are using a legacy system which stores a record creation datetime as per the system time (available in taskbar, etc). Now I need to capture the current datetime using JavaScript for a certain condition and calculate the difference between created datetime and current datetime. So, what would you suggest here?